# Query an Unrelated Table in Report- Calculated Field

Tags: ms-access

I'm creating a report in which I'd like to get a value from an unrelated table

*SELECT Letter FROM AnotherTable WHERE ThisField>=Tablex.Low AND ThisField<=Tablex.High*   (This gets a letter from a grades table)

The query works separately but not in the report when used in a calculated field. I only get #Name?

The report is based on a CrossTab, so I cannot use a subquery in it

Access 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL cannot be used as ControlSource for a textbox.

Try using *DLookup*:

```
=DLookup("[Letter]","[AnotherTable]","[ThisField] Between " & TableX!Low & " And " & TableX!High & "")
```

**Edit**:

Try with either:

```
=DLookUp("[Letter]","[Grades]","[AVG] Between " & [ArtsLow] & " And " & [ArtsHigh] & "")
```

or, if *AVG* is text:

```
=DLookUp("[Letter]","[Grades]","[AVG] Between '" & [ArtsLow] & "' And '" & [ArtsHigh] & "'")
```

**Edit2:**

It's the other way round:

```
=DLookUp("[Letter]","[Grades]","" & Nz([AVG],-1) & " Between [ArtsLow] And [ArtsHigh]")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot especially for your speed... However, its asking for AnotherTable ... as if it were a parameter.

Comment: Replace _AnotherTable_ with the real name of your table or query.

Comment: Hello, I had replaced the name so that the query looks like

Comment: '=DLookUp("[Letter]","[Grades]","[AVG] Between " & [Grades]![ArtsLow] & " And " & [Grades]![ArtsHigh] & "") '    The error I get is _#Type!_    @Gustav

Comment: Hello, I've actually tried both and neither works... It however seems to understand both (Text or Number) because when I insert the range  ArtsLow and ArtsHigh, it inserts the first letter in the table.... Here's googledrive link [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_Y1srbm0OC0WEhhRUhrMm53eEE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, it's the other way 'round. See edit. You may have to rename your textbox AVG to something else, and recheck the expression in the answer.

Comment: PS: Be careful posting restricted data.